# Extract code from nested curly braces, including multiple internal curly braces in PHP

Tags: php, regex

So, I got some ideas off here about how to do this and took on board some of the code suggestions; I have LaTeX files with components in the form 
`{upper}{lower}` where `upper` could be anything from plain text to LaTeX including its own nested {} and `lower` could be blank or substantial latex. Desired output is a pair of PHP strings `$upper` and `$lower` that contain only the content of the two parent braces.

```
$upperlowerQ='some string';  // in format {upper}{lower}
$qparts=nestor($upperlowerQ);
$upper=$qparts[0];
$lower=$qparts[1];


function nestor($subject) {
    $result = false;    
    preg_match_all('~[^{}]+|\{(?<nested>(?R)*)\}~', $subject, $matches);

    foreach($matches['nested'] as $match) {
        if ($match != "") {
            $result[] = $match;
            $nesty = nestor($match);
            if ($nesty) 
                $result = array_merge($result,$nesty); 
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This function works for about 95% of my data (this upper/lower splitting is called in a loop for about 1,000 times) but it is failing on a few. An example of something it fails on looks like this:

```
{Draw an example of a reciprocal graph in the form $y=\frac{a}{x}$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-8,xmax=8,ymin=-5,ymax=12,samples=50,grid=both,grid style={gray!30},xtick={-8,...,8},ytick={-5,...,12},axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left, axis lines=middle]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\par
%ans: smooth reciprocal function plotted.
}
```

which gives:
`$upper` as `Draw an example of a reciprocal graph in the form $y=\frac{a}{x}$` (which is correct) but `$lower` as `a`, which is the numerator of the fraction in the upper part... any ideas appreciated. It is always `$lower` that is wrong... `$upper` seems correct.

Comment: What should lower be?

Comment: `$lower` should be `\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-8,xmax=8,ymin=-5,ymax=12,samples=50,grid=both,grid style={gray!30},xtick={-8,...,8},ytick={-5,...,12},axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left, axis lines=middle]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\par
%ans: smooth reciprocal function plotted.`

Comment: Can you please provide better input and what exactly you want to match/extract. Regardless function `nesty`, `nestor` that's included in the sample and [produces this output](https://eval.in/417089).

Comment: So I want to supply a string that will definitely contain two pairs of `{}`, and within each pair of `{}` there could be anything ranging from nothing to multi-line LaTeX code that may itself include `{}` symbols

Comment: See [if this at eval.in](https://eval.in/417101) helps. Using regex [like this:](https://regex101.com/r/iR3gA2/2) `{((?:[^}{]+|(?R))*)}` for only extracting what's inside the outer `{` `}` and to check if exactly 2 items are matched by returned *$matchcount* of `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Wow, that appears to work perfectly, thank very much! @Jonny5

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helps :) was not sure if understanding right.

Answer (score 2):

For any future readers, @Jonny5's response above worked perfectly. [eval.in](https://eval.in/417101)

---

*Added from comments*

Try using regex [like this:](https://regex101.com/r/iR3gA2/2) `{((?:[^}{]+|(?R))*)}` for only extracting what's inside the outer `{` `}` and to check if exactly 2 items are matched by returned *matchcount* of [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$upper = ""; $lower = "";

if(preg_match_all('/{((?:[^}{]+|(?R))*)}/', $str, $out) == 2) {
  $upper=$out[1][0]; $lower=$out[1][1];
}
```

See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/417101)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. They become useless when the link breaks and that happens pretty often.